# Setting an environment variable for maven-driven integration tests

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, citrus-framework

Is is possible to set an environment variable from within a Citrus Framework integration test? I am asking because my services use log4j to log console output and the configuration file (log4j2-spring.xml) uses environment variables to set log file names, etc. It would be convenient to be able to do this.

Comment: Could you give more details? What kind of variable you need? In Citrus documentation you can find a lot examples how to create variables (variable(), createVariable()) in citrus test and even global variables.

Comment: A system environment variable. For example, on a Unix/Linux system, something you would set with `export VAR=value`.

Answer (score 1):

In general changing environment settings for the already running JVM instance and getting the changes updated in your running system (e.g. Log4J logging appenders) is not easy and might not work in all situations. So I am pretty sure this is not what you should try to do.

In terms of Citrus you can run any Java or Groovy code as part of the integration tests so you can also have all imaginable hacks as part of an integration test. But as I already said this is not what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was not so much a question of how to do this in the Citrus Framework, but rather with setting up the environment variables for maven integration tests.

I was able to set the environment variables I needed for the integration test(s) run via maven by adding the following to the spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      ...
      <environmentVariables>
        <env-var-name>env var value</env-var-name>
        ...
      </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
```

Once the appropriate variables are set, test console output is logged where directed by configuration in `log4j2-test.xml`, located in `src/test/resources`.

See issue [Citrus Framework logging - how to enable/use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153773/citrus-framework-logging-how-to-enable-use).