# Citrus Framework logging - how to enable/use

Tags: log4j2, citrus-framework

The Citrus Framework documentation indicates that integration test console output can be logged via the SLF4J logging system. It's not obvious whether this is automatic, or whether it needs to be enabled in some way. My experience indicates that it's not enabled as no log file containing what appears on the test run console has been produced.

My application uses Log4J with an associated `log4j2-spring.xml` file (in `src/main/resources`) to define log formats and files. When an integration test is run via Citrus, the application console output (and other information) is properly logged to the files specified in the Log4J config file. There is however, no Citrus console output logged anywhere (except on the console).

How do I enable the logging of the Citrus test console output? I created a separate `log4j.xml` that I placed in `src/test/resources`, but this seems to have been ignored.

Do I need to specify a separate logger in the config that's specific for Citrus output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citrus uses SLF4J which is a facade to several other logging frameworks out there. So you need to pick your favorite logging framework (in your case Log4J) and add a SLF4J logger binding for that logging framework. This is all described in the [SLF4J user manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping)

I would suggest to add the SLF4J logger binding for Log4J as a test scoped dependency in your project. Also depending on your Log4J configuration setup you may need to add a Log4J logger configuration for `com.consol.citrus` and set a proper logging level for that in order to see the Citrus output logged by Log4J.

Comment: I am using Log4J 2 with these applications and it is configured via the Spring Boot starter for Log4J2 (spring-boot-starter-log4j2). I don't know the differences between Log4J 1 and Log4J 2. With that in mind, does the Citrus logging work with Log4J 2?

Comment: I have an existing `log4j2-spring.xml` configuration file located in `src/main/resources` that I use to control logging output for the application during operation. When I run integration tests via Citrus, will this config be used, or should I define a separate one under `src/test/resources` for unit/integration test logging?

Comment: I have also looked at the SLF4J user manual as suggested. There is no indication of Log4J 2 mentioned. I'm wondering whether SLF4J works with Log4J 2.

Comment: Yes, Log4J2 provides the SLF4J binding: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/dependency-info.html

Comment: I found an article that gave me an idea that I tried and it worked. The article (https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/configure-log4j2-for-junit/) made reference to a separate log4j configuration file named `log4j2-test.xml` and placed in `src/test/resources`. After a little experimentation I got it to log what I wanted in the file(s) I wanted.