# Citrus Framework - echo action does not "echo"

Tags: citrus-framework

I am attempting to debug/trace an integration test written with the Citrus Framework. Among the various test "actions" that can be taken, there is an echo action which is supposed to do what you might expect: echo something to the console log. The problem is: it does **not** echo.

When I run the integration test (via Maven failsafe plugin), errors from the test failing appear on the console, but nothing else.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**:

This appears to only be a problem when running the integration tests as part of a maven build. When the test is run from eclipse, the complete console log appears.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with your test names. Failsafe Maven plugin by default has a naming convention and only runs those tests that follow this convention. So your test names must match a pattern.

Please review the default [naming pattern in failsafe plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) and see if this fixes your issue.

Comment: My integration test class is named with an ending "IT", so it should be picked up by the failsafe plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to get logging to capture the Citrus integration test console output. See related issue [Citrus Framework logging - how to enable/use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60153773/citrus-framework-logging-how-to-enable-use).